# Get parent category for CPT

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm working on an index page that lists all posts for a custom post type. I've been listing the categories for each post using `<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'genre', ' ',' &#8226; ')); ?>`.

We need to add sub-categories but I don't want these to display on the index page - just the parent category. Have tried using `get_term_parents_list` and a few other examples from here but can't get anything working.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_the_terms` filter to change the terms to return.

```
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'only_parent_genre', 10, 3);
function only_parent_genre($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy) {

    // TODO for you : Add condition to heck if you are not on your custom index too.
    if(is_admin() || $taxonomy !== 'genre') {
        return $terms;
    }

    // Loop over terms and if parent is something different than 0, it means that's its a child term
    foreach($terms as $key => $term) {
        if($term->parent !== 0) {
            unset($terms[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $terms;
}
```